# Javascript: Error when loading the page

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm making an API call, and every time the page loads it comes with this error and I don't know why.
Can anyone tell me why? 
I've tried to put it:

[image: What browser says]

Here is the markup where I use the total amount:

```
<div class="summary__graph">
        <div class="graph__header">
          <h3 class="headline">Fordeling</h3>
          <p class="answers">{{company.amount.total}} besvarelser</p>
        </div>
```

Here's where I define my company I fill with total value

```
 data () {
    return {
      selected: 1,
      datacollection: null,
      datacollection2: null,
      datacollection3: null,
      company: '',
      isActive: false,
      scoreLine: null,
      timeBar: null,
      answerPercent: null

    }
  },
```

vue.js mounted and methods

```
  mounted () {
    this.getStoreScore()
    this.fillData()
    this.fillData2()
    this.fillData3()
    this.fillDataScoreLine()
    this.fillDataTimeBar()
    this.fillDataAnswerPercent()
  },


getStoreScore () {
      return axios.post('API', {
        storeId: '5b7515ed5d53fa0020557447'
      }).then(response => {
        this.company = {
          'storeScore': response.data.result,
          'amount': {
            'total': response.data.amount.total,
            'zero': {
              'amount': response.data.amount.zero,
              'percentage': response.data.amount.zero / response.data.amount.total * 100
            },
            'one': {
              'amount': response.data.amount.one,
              'percentage': response.data.amount.one / response.data.amount.total * 100
            },
            'two': {
              'amount': response.data.amount.two,
              'percentage': response.data.amount.two / response.data.amount.total * 100
            },
            'three': {
              'amount': response.data.amount.three,
              'percentage': response.data.amount.three / response.data.amount.total * 100
            }
          }
        }
        return this.company
      })
    },
```

Can anyone tell me why it gives me that error? :D

Comment: `company.amount.total` is not defined before `axios.post(..)` respond.. either initialize it to null before or wrap your html with if

Comment: I recommend editing your question to include the text of your error instead of pasting an image. This makes it easier to read for people trying to help you and easier for others to find the same issue on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're making an API call, the page gets rendered before you receive any data. You get the error because `company.amount` is undefined when the page gets rendered. There are a few fixes possible: either you delay your page rendering until all the data is received, or you write a quick if condition around the

```
<p class="answers">{{company.amount.total}} besvarelser</p>
```

More info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Edit: Your code would become

```
<p v-if="company.amount" class="answers">{{company.amount.total}} besvarelser</p>
```